# No new request for a new Image with the same URL

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers

I want to refresh an image that is regularly updated on the server, so I load it like this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = myCallback;
img.src = imageUrl;
```

imageUrl is always the same, and I set these HTTP headers to force the browser to issue a new request every time I try to load the image:

```
Cache-Control: public,max-age=0
Expires: -1
Last-modified: Mon, 21 Nov 2008 01:03:33 GMT
ETag: 1234
```

But it only works on Chrome; Firefox, Opera, IE and Safari only send a request to the server the first time, then I always get the cached image.

If I add img.src = '' to myCallback, it works on Opera and IE, but still not in Firefox and Safari (I only tried Firefox 11).

I could add a random query string to my URL, but it would consume much more bandwidth, as most of the time the server replies with 304 Not modified.

Is there a way to make it work on Firefox ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on inconsistent browser and server behavior, you could make it a two-step process:

1. Make an AJAX call to a URL that the client can use to find out if the image has been updated (force no cache on that one)
2. If it has been updated, update the `image.src` with a new URL (new string appended to the base URL)

You could use something like the UNIX timestamp of the last update to the image as the random string appended to the URL.

Example using JQuery-style pseudocode (may or may not work as is):

```
function updateImage() {
    $.get('/HasImageBeenUpdated?', function(answer) {
       // answer could be JSON: {wasUpdated: true, newImageUrl: 'url'} 
       if (answer.wasUpdated === true) {
            $('#theImage').attr('src', answer.newImageUrl);
        }
    });
}
setInterval(updateImage, 1000); // update every second
```

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite cache each time, append a random number at the end of URL as a parameter.

Comment: As I said: _I could add a random query string to my URL, but it would consume much more bandwidth, as most of the time the server replies with 304 Not modified._

Comment: can you make a file on server, which compare and see if image is new, on yes, it will serve new image.

Comment: @Jazz I think what he means is that the random string will force Firefox to send the request, but then you could have a script on the server check if the file has been updated before actually sending it. If it hasn't been modified send 304 not modified, instead of the image.

Comment: If I reply 304, how can the browser have a cached version with the random string in the URL?